# How do i compile a drools project using ant?

Tags: java, ant, drools

I'm working on a drools project using eclipse but i would like to compile it with ant. I defined my build.xml file as follow :

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="manifest.dir" value="ressources"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="core.Core"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<path id="lib">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="lib"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" manifest="${manifest.dir}/META-INF/kmodule.xml"/> 
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
      <classpath>
        <path refid="lib"/>
        <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

However, while developping in eclipse, i defined several kiesessions in the kmodule.xml file and thus when i try to compile via ant, i have this error :

```
 [main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: colorSession
 [main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: rulesSession
```

Does anyone know how to insert it in ant's build file? I assume I'll have to modify the manifest but I don't know exactly how to do so.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: You need to make sure that wherever you put your kmodule.xml file, that your ant build process puts that directory onto the classpath. For a maven project, `src/main/resources` is always put on the classpath, so the internal `META-INF/kmodule.xml` is automatically added by maven; you need to make sure your ant build does the same with wherever you've located your XML in your file structure.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! So I added a line in my path token : <fileset dir="${resources.dir}"/> (where resources.dir = src/main/resources) but I have the same error. Should i proceed differently?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured out what was the problem. As Roddy said, my "src/main/resources" was not in the classpath. I just added a line in my taget "run" to add it to the class path. Here is the corrected code for someone who might need it

```
<project name="test" basedir="." default="main">
<property name="src.dir"     value="src/main/java"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="resources.dir" value="src/main/resources"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="core.Core"/>

<target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<path id="lib">
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
  <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="lib"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
  <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}"/> 
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
  <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="${resources.dir}"/>
      <path refid="lib"/>
      <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```